# Are there any thesauruses in Esperanto?

Tags: resources

[PIV](http://vortaro.net/) only contains definitions which, in need, can be used to find used to find similar words. In a thesaurus each word maps to a list of similar words like in [thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/buttock?s=t). Do you know of any such internet (or physical) thesauruses?

Comment: Edited the title for a slight grammar mistake so as not to confuse other people.

Answer (score 5):

There's "Esperantonimoj"

https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esperantonimoj

As an alternative, you can use a national language thesaurus and a bilingual dictionary to find word suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

There's [thesaurus](http://zz9pza.net/eobot/fontkodo/datumoj/tez.txt) online that EoBot from the IRC chatroom ##esperanto uses, but I don't know its origin.

Ekzistas interrete [datumo](http://zz9pza.net/eobot/fontkodo/datumoj/tez.txt) por EoBot de IRC babilejo ##esperanto, sed mi ne scias ĝian originon.

Answer (score 3):

UEA has one thesaurus: http://uea.org/vikio/Teza%C5%ADro

> La ĉefa uzo de tezaŭro (etime trezoro) estas pliriĉigi la
>   vortoprovizon. Trezoro mem devenas de vorto signifanta "trovi". Aliaj
>   nomoj: Analogia vortaro, laŭtema vortaro.
>
> Vortoj vekigas ideojn. Ideoj kristaliĝas en vortojn.
>
> La unua uzo de ĉi-tiu tezaŭro, estas permesi vin pli rapide retrovi forgesitan vorton, dum vi verkas tekston. Sed ĝi povas ankaŭ veki ideon al kiu vi ne jam pensis.
>
> Tial, tiu tezaŭro ne nur temas pri sinonimoj, sed pri ideoj rilatitaj
>   al la vorto.